# build script in unix

Tags: python, shell, unix, build

Is there a way in Unix shell script to install different packages from different sources like rpm, building from source, in a specific sequence i.e.

1. package A -- rpm installer
2. package B -- install from source only if package has installed correctly else roll back
3. package C -- install from source only if package D is installed

since I am new to Unix shell scripting, I earlier tried to install each package separately but now I want to automate this process, Please let me know a way of achieving this on OpenSUSE SE linux.

Comment: Um, sure, but why? Just build RPMs.

Comment: Do you mean to incorporate all these build processes in a single rpm? I am new to that too :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply list all the commands you ran to install the different packages in a single script. Since you're new to shell scripting you might want to post the result on [CR.SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) - there are a billion and one gotchas in shell scripting.